# Append special character to a value in python

Tags: python, boto, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to delete all stacks those environments(instances) were terminated. while passing the stack_name to the delete_stack it's throwing an error. I've tried to add the special characters (such as '') to the value of stack_name,but there was no luck. Can someone please help me to fix the issue. Thanks in advance!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import boto
import boto.ec2
import boto.cloudformation
import re
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

utclast = datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(2)

conn = boto.cloudformation.connect_to_region('us-west-1',aws_access_key_id = '<access_key>',aws_secret_access_key = '<secret_key>')
conn_ec2 = boto.ec2.connect_to_region('us-west-1',aws_access_key_id = '<access_key>',aws_secret_access_key = '<secret_key>')

stacks = conn.list_stacks()
for stackSumm in stacks:
    pattern = re.compile("Testupload-env([a-zA-Z0-9]+)")
    match = pattern.match(stackSumm.stack_name)
    if stackSumm.stack_status in "CREATE_COMPLETE" and match and stackSumm.stack_name in match.string:
        m = re.split(r'Testupload-', stackSumm.stack_name)
        instance = conn_ec2.get_all_instances(filters={"tag:Name": m[1]})
        if not instance:

            try:
                    print "Trying to delete stack: %s" % stackSumm.stack_name
                    conn.delete_stack(stackSumm.stack_name)

            except boto.exception.BotoServerError, e:
                    print e.error_message
```

Error:

```
File "delete_stack.py", line 7, in <module>
    conn.delete_stack(Testupload-envmeraleb8b01739116b0f36d17a2b5445b949f592bb625-6293)
NameError: name 'Testupload' is not defined
```

Comment: The exception you show doesn't come from any of the code you've shown, but soemewhere that you're calling `conn.delete_stack` with an argument that's missing quotation marks.

Comment: post the code that raises the error.

Comment: what is in your `stackSumm`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of you posted code generated the error, but the NameError says that you didn't provide a valid stack name

> delete_stack(stack_name_or_id)
>   Deletes a specified stack. Once the call completes successfully, stack deletion starts. Deleted stacks do not show up in the DescribeStacks API if the deletion has been completed successfully.
>
> Parameters:    stack_name_or_id (string) – The name or the unique identifier associated with the stack.

The name/id should be a string, a string in python must be quoted, either by single quotes or double quotes

```
stack_name = "Testupload-envmeraleb8b01739116b0f36d17a2b5445b949f592bb625-6293"
conn.delete_stack(stack_name)
```

Comment: this is a premature answer. let him post the actual code that raised the error.

Comment: @dbliss  you can see the error OP posted. Doesn't it mean anything to you?